# RVM + Zsh "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work"

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'll start by saying I'm not an expert at command-line, so I really only barely know what I'm doing.

I cannot get RVM and oh-my-zsh to play nice together. I've tried several different solutions posted around, some on SO, but nothing I have found seems to fix the issue.

Initially, someone else setup RVM on my machine. I later setup oh-my-zsh myself, and remember having a lot of trouble doing so.

My `.zhsrc` file is completely default except for these 2 lines

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH

#pretty sure this line does nothing, although I've seen this fix around
# several places. I noticed that I don't seem to have an .rvm file in my 
# home directory which would be an issue, but I have no idea how to 
# go about correcting this.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I added the `/usr/local/rvm` to the Path directive as zsh returns `zsh: rvm command not found` without it there. Otherwise most rvm command work, with the exception of `rvm use` which throws the following error:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I have ensured the profile preferences on my profile in iTerm2 are set to "Login Shell" as recommended by RVM

[image: iTerm2 Preferences - Login Shell]

I have tried changing these preferences to the "Command" option and using the recommended `/bin/bash/ --login` as the command, however zsh no longer appears to work when this happens. Changing the command to `/bin/zsh/ --login` allows zsh to work again but does not solve the problem as I still get the "RVM is not a function" error when trying to run `rvm use`

The default ruby in RVM is set to 2.0.0. I can run `ruby -v` in my home folder and get the ruby version output which shows the default version.

Working on rails projects, I can run all rails commands IF the Gemfile specifies ruby 2.0.0, the default. However on a project that uses a different version, I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

Then I cannot run `rvm use 1.9.3` as it returns the above mentioned error.

### How can I make zsh play nice with RVM?

Some info about my setup:

- Mac OSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks)
- iTerm2
- Zsh 5.0.2 with oh-my-zsh
- RVM 1.5.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out that RVM was installed in the wrong place. When I had initially installed RVM I believe I did so with the `sudo` command, which ran the multi-user install (installed to `/usr/local/rvm`), and not the single user (should be in `~/.rvm/scrips/rvm`), which is why all the posted solutions were not working for me.

I had to uninstall RVM with `rvm implode`. There were some permissions issues, so I had to manually go in and delete the files that could not be deleted. Ran the curl command to re-install RVM and now it's installed in the correct place.

Sourcing RVM in my `.zshrc` with `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` now works properly and I can switch between rubies.

Answer (score 85):

For me, I just had to add

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

to my ~/.zshrc and it started working, after having the same error message as in this SO question.

Comment: and if you installed rvm globally (i.e. in /usr/local/rvm), add
`source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` instead.

Answer (score 6):

@trustkr's answer worked for me, but would like to add...

I ran into this issue immediately after install of rvm. In order for the

```
source
```

to work in in the ~/.zshrc file to work, you will need either start a new terminal session and work there OR you can run

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

in the same terminal session in which you installed.

[Mac OS 10.10.5 - iTerm - zsh]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue added this one line at end of .zshrc file

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

and works now everything works fine on my ubuntu 16.04 operating system :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the following:

> $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

then run this

> $ type rvm | head -n 1

and the result will be like

> rvm is a shell function from /home/sun/.rvm/scripts/cli

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

1) In the terminal run :

```
which rvm
```

The output in my case is --->  **/usr/share/rvm**

2) Open .zshrc file

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

add "**source** + *the_path_to_your_rvm* + **/scripts/rvm**", in my case it's :

```
source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

3) save the file (.zshrc)

4) close the terminal and open it again